# Use override instead of event subscription in a class

Tags: c#, .net, oop, events, overriding

Currently I'm struggeling, whether to override an existing method, for example `OnActivate` rather than subsripte to an `event` in the same class.

For example I have the following class, which implements an event:

```
public class Base
{
    public delegate void DoSomeThing(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public event DoSomeThing DoSomeThingEventHandler;

    public virtual void OnDoSomeThing(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DoSomeThingEventHandler != null)
        {
            DoSomeThingEventHandler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a class which derives from `Base` which wants to be notified, if `DoSomeThing` gets called. Should I override `DoSomeThing` or should I subscribe to the event:

Solution one:

```
public class B1 : Base
{
    public override void OnDoSomeThing(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do some stuff here

        base.OnDoSomeThing(e);
    }
}
```

Second solution

```
public class B2 : Base
{
    public B2()
    {
        DoSomeThingEventHandler += B2_DoSomeThingEventHandler;
    }

    private void B2_DoSomeThingEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do some thing here
    }
}
```

Would you prefer solution `B1` or `B2`?

Thank you all!

Comment: you have to override the event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case overriding is a better option but first execute the base class implementation, so that you don't break anything and after that do whatever you want in the derived class like:

```
public override void OnDoSomeThing(EventArgs e)
{

  base.OnDoSomeThing(e);

  // write here whatever needed

}
```

Comment: Ok, putting it on the top makes sense. Just some `if`-statements could be needed, when i want to avoid calling any events...

Comment: yes after calling base you can write whatever your business logic is for derived type